# Having a div width equal to the contener

Tags: css, width

I can find a solution to have a caption, with a width equal to the picture it describes :

Look a this jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/rbhmozvc/2/
When you arrive, everything is ok, but if you resize the height of the browser, the caption becomes larger than the contener, instead of create a new line.

Any idea ? Thanks !

The HTML :

```
<div id="contener">
<div id="inside">
    <div class="pic">
        <img class="img" src="http://www.wikinoticia.com/images2//s3.alt1040.com/files/2013/02/Twitter-ahora-habla-LOLCat.jpg">
        <div class="caption">Hello, This is a caption - Summer Spring 2014</div>
    </div>
     <div class="pic carre">
        <img class="img" src="http://www.wikinoticia.com/images2//s3.alt1040.com/files/2013/02/Twitter-ahora-habla-LOLCat.jpg">
        <div class="caption">Hello, This is a caption - Summer Spring 2014</div>
    </div>
    <div class="pic">
        <img class="img" src="http://www.wikinoticia.com/images2//s3.alt1040.com/files/2013/02/Twitter-ahora-habla-LOLCat.jpg">
        <div class="caption">Hello, This is a caption - Summer Spring 2014</div>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have `white-space: nowrap` set....that would probably do it.

Comment: Thanks but if i delete the white-space : nowrap, the image are not one next to the other, and the caption is still larger : https://jsfiddle.net/rbhmozvc/3/

Comment: The I suggest that the way you are going about the layout & HTML structure needs some changes. Text should be in text elements to start with not bare text nodes in a div.

Comment: By text elements, you mean a span ?

Answer (score 1):

Its because you have white-space set to no-wrap.

```
#contener {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```